# Flutter: Setting the height of the AppBar

Tags: dart, material-design, flutter

How can I simply set the height of the `AppBar` in Flutter?

The title of the bar should be staying centered vertically (in that `AppBar`).

Comment: @Mans It's about 'getting' the height of the `AppBar`, not 'setting' it.

Comment: Did you took a look at [this](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/AppBar-class.html)? You could also create your own widget as an AppBar and set it's height.

Comment: @Leviathlon my bad. check my answer for (hopefully) some better help

Answer (score 330, accepted):

You can use [PreferredSize](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSize-class.html):

```
class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'Example',
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
          preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0), // here the desired height
          child: AppBar(
            // ...
          )
        ),
        body: // ...
      )
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This increases the size of the AppBar, but doesn't centre the text.

Comment: You can use `centerTitle` property to center it.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad That centers it horizontally but does not center it vertically.

Comment: @CopsOnRoad I know, but I was just pointing out what the OP is asking for.

Comment: You can wrap the title in a container and set a top margin to center it vertically

Comment: Can this be set at `MaterialApp` similar to how `ThemeData` can be set at top level? I am looking for a way to avoid writing overrides for every AppBar or custom AppBar class.

Comment: @user482594 you can make a separate class for app bar and use it everywhere u want

Comment: @Giraldi You can center it by using flexibleSpace property, check out [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65547907/6618622)

Comment: This do not show the drawer if you have one on the scaffold.

Answer (score 84):

#### Use `toolbarHeight`:

[image]

---

There's no longer a need to use `PreferredSize`. Use `toolbarHeight` with `flexibleSpace`.

```dart
AppBar(
  toolbarHeight: 120, // Set this height
  flexibleSpace: Container(
    color: Colors.orange,
    child: Column(
      children: [
        Text('1'),
        Text('2'),
        Text('3'),
        Text('4'),
      ],
    ),
  ),
)
```

Comment: This should be the correct answer. It solves the problem directly from the widget's parameters.

Comment: Much better solution.  Far simpler.

Comment: If you use your own custom AppBar, this might not be the solution. It's the material UI solution.

Answer (score 54):

You can use `PreferredSize` and `flexibleSpace` for it:

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(100.0),
  child: AppBar(
    automaticallyImplyLeading: false, // hides leading widget
    flexibleSpace: SomeWidget(),
  )
),
```

This way you can keep the `elevation` of `AppBar` for keeping its shadow visible and have custom height, which is what I was just looking for. You do have to set the spacing in `SomeWidget`, though.

Answer (score 35):

The easiest way is to use `toolbarHeight` property in your AppBar
**Example :**

```
AppBar(
   title: Text('Flutter is great'),
   toolbarHeight: 100,
  ),
```

> You can add `flexibleSpace` property in your appBar for more flexibility

**Output**:

[image]

#### For more controls , Use the [PreferedSize](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSize-class.html)  widget to create your own appBar

**Example** :

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
     preferredSize: Size(100, 80), //width and height 
          // The size the AppBar would prefer if there were no other constraints.
     child: SafeArea(
       child: Container(
         height: 100,
         color: Colors.red,
         child: Center(child: Text('Fluter is great')),
       ),
     ),
),
```

> Don't forget to use a `SafeArea` widget if you don't have a safeArea

**Output :**

[image]

Comment: I already provided `toolBarHeight` solution, second "For more controls , Use the PreferedSize " -- Not necessarily, `toolbarHeight` does the job well.

Answer (score 16):

**At the time of writing this, I was not aware of `PreferredSize`. Cinn's answer is better to achieve this.**

You can create your own custom widget with a custom height:

```
import "package:flutter/material.dart";

class Page extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Column(children : <Widget>[new CustomAppBar("Custom App Bar"), new Container()],);
  }
}


class CustomAppBar extends StatelessWidget {

  final String title;
  final double barHeight = 50.0; // change this for different heights 

  CustomAppBar(this.title);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    final double statusbarHeight = MediaQuery
        .of(context)
        .padding
        .top;

    return new Container(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.only(top: statusbarHeight),
      height: statusbarHeight + barHeight,
      child: new Center(
        child: new Text(
          title,
          style: new TextStyle(fontSize: 20.0, fontWeight: FontWeight.bold),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

In addition to @Cinn's answer, you can define a class like this

```
class MyAppBar extends AppBar with PreferredSizeWidget {
  @override
  get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(50);

  MyAppBar({Key key, Widget title}) : super(
    key: key,
    title: title,
    // maybe other AppBar properties
  );
}
```

or this way

```
class MyAppBar extends PreferredSize {
  MyAppBar({Key key, Widget title}) : super(
    key: key,
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50),
    child: AppBar(
      title: title,
      // maybe other AppBar properties
    ),
  );
}
```

and then use it instead of standard one

Answer (score 12):

You can simply use toolbarHeight, as follows:

```
        appBar: AppBar(
        toolbarHeight: 70.0, // add this line
        centerTitle: true,   // add this line
        title: Text('your title'),
        ),
```

but if you have any actions the code above doesn't work as you want
you can use this code

```
AppBar(
    centerTitle: true,
    title: Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
      child: Stack(
        alignment: Alignment.center,
        children: [
          Row(
            mainAxisSize: MainAxisSize.max,
            mainAxisAlignment: MainAxisAlignment.center,
            children: [
              Text('Chats', style: TextStyle(color:Colors.black),),
              Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.black,),
            ],
          ),
          Align(
            alignment: Alignment.centerRight,
            child: Icon(Icons.add, color: Colors.black,),
          ),
        ],
      ),
    ),
  )
```

Comment: This only changes the height of the toolbar component. It won't work if you use other components too and want everything centered.

Comment: Can you explain the problem that appeared to you when you used this method?

Comment: If an AppBar contains "leading" or "actions" widgets, they are not affected by the toolbar height.

Comment: Yes, you are right, but he did not mention that. I provided another solution that fits what you said

Answer (score 6):

[Cinn's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089994/flutter-setting-the-height-of-the-appbar/51459503#51459503) is great, but there's **one thing** wrong with it.

The `PreferredSize` widget will start immediately at the top of the screen, without accounting for the status bar, so some of its height will be shadowed by the status bar's height. This also accounts for the side notches.

**The solution**: Wrap the `preferredSize`'s child with a `SafeArea`

```
appBar: PreferredSize(
  //Here is the preferred height.
  preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0),
  child: SafeArea(
    child: AppBar(
      flexibleSpace: ...
    ),
  ),
),
```

If you don't wanna use the flexibleSpace property, then there's no need for all that, because the other properties of the `AppBar` will account for the status bar automatically.

Comment: but `SafeArea` is to reduce status bar height, yet you added it again with `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top`? I think SafeArea is not needed here.

Comment: @Ryde The `SafeArea` is important so that the app bar doesn't overlap with the status bar, but the `MediaQuery.of(context).padding.top` is not needed actually. I've edited the answer, thanks.

Answer (score 5):

simply use toolbar height ...

```
AppBar(
 title: Text("NASHIR'S APP"),
 toolbarHeight: 100,
),
```

Comment: Please ensure that your code has no syntax errors before submitting.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the toolbarHeight property of Appbar, it does exactly what you want.

Answer (score 2):

```
class AppBarWidget extends StatelessWidget with PreferredSizeWidget {
  final String title;
  const AppBarWidget({Key? key, required this.title}) : super(key: key);

  @override`enter code here`
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return AppBar(

  title: Text(title),
  centerTitle: true,
  elevation: 0,
  actions: [
    Padding(
      padding: const EdgeInsets.only(right: 10),
      child: IconButton(
        icon: const FaIcon(FontAwesomeIcons.language),
        onPressed: () {},
      ),
    ),
    
  ],
);
  }

 @override

  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(40);// change
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

This is simplest and easiest way to change appbar height without changing original theme.

```
class AppBarSectionView extends StatefulWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {
 const AppBarSectionView({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

 @override
 _AppBarSectionViewState createState() => _AppBarSectionViewState();

 @override
 Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight + 20);
}

class _AppBarSectionViewState extends State<AppBarSectionView> {
 @override
 Widget build(BuildContext context) {
   return AppBar(
     toolbarHeight: widget.preferredSize.height ,
     backgroundColor: Colors.red,
     leading: const Icon(Icons.arrow_back_ios_rounded),
     title: const Text("This Is Title"),
   );
 }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [**PreferredSize**](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/PreferredSize-class.html), by this use can set multiple children widget inside their

```
 appBar: PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size(MediaQuery.of(context).size.width, 75),
    child: Column(children: [
      AppBar(
        centerTitle: true,
        toolbarHeight: 74,
        backgroundColor: Colors.white,
        elevation: 0,
        title: Column(
          children: [
            Text(
              viewModel.headingText,
              style: sfDisplay16500Text,
            ),
            SizedBox(
              height: 8.0,
            ),
            Text(
              viewModel.url.toString(),
              style: sfDisplay10400LightBlackText,
              maxLines: 1,
              overflow: TextOverflow.ellipsis,
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
    ]),
  ),
```

or just directly use **[toolbarHeight](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/AppBar/toolbarHeight.html)** property for only increase hight of appBar.

```
appBar: AppBar(
          title: Text('AppBar Texr'),
          toolbarHeight: 200.0, // double
        ),
```

Answer (score 1):

***toolbarHeight Property***

```
AppBar(
   toolbarHeight: 120,
),
```

Source: [Appbar Size Flutter - AmmarJaved](https://ammarjaved.com/appbar-size-flutter-setting-the-height/)

Answer (score 0):

Extend AppBar class and override **preferredSize**

```
class AppBarCustom extends AppBar {
  @override
  Size get preferredSize => Size.fromHeight(100);
}
```

then use it as you would use AppBar class

```
class MyHomePage extends StatelessWidget {
 @override
   Widget build(BuildContext context) {
     return MaterialApp(
       home: Scaffold(
       appBar: AppBarCustom(),
       body:
       ),
     );
   }
 }
```

Answer (score -15):

If you are in Visual Code, **Ctrl + Click** on AppBar function.

```html
Widget demoPage() {
  AppBar appBar = AppBar(
    title: Text('Demo'),
  );
  return Scaffold(
    appBar: appBar,
    body: /*
    page body
    */,
  );
}
```

And edit this piece.

```css
app_bar.dart will open and you can find 
    preferredSize = new Size.fromHeight(kToolbarHeight + (bottom?.preferredSize?.height ?? 0.0)),
```

Difference of height!

[image: sample image]

[image: sample image]

Comment: This is not what he asked for. He want the title to be vertically centered

Comment: centerTitle:true;
can be used to do it.

Comment: vertical center, not horizontal

Comment: So it doesn't read new height. I don't think tinkering source file like app_bar.dart, for changing it, would be good idea though.

Comment: It's a very bad idea to ever edit sources of a framework. It will break your app if you update the framework.

Comment: Dear friend, not to be rude. But you should delete this answer. It is wrong and could mislead other beginners.