# How to change appBar size in Scaffold

Tags: flutter, dart

how to change appbar size while we return in Scaffold?

I can't change Scaffold to MaterialApp or something else,

my code:

```
        return Scaffold(
          appBar: AppBar(
            title: Image(
              image: AssetImage('assets/images/logo.png'),
              height: 70.0,
            ),
            centerTitle: true,
            backgroundColor: Colors.white,
            iconTheme: IconThemeData(color: Color.fromRGBO(9, 133, 46, 100)),     
            actions: <Widget>[
              UserIcon(),
              IconButton(
                icon: Icon(
                  Icons.shopping_cart,
                  color: Color.fromRGBO(9, 133, 46, 100),
                  size: 30.0,
                ),
                onPressed: () {
                  //
                },
              ),
            ],       
          ),
          body: body,
        );
```

Comment: Can you drop a picture of what you want to achieve?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Flutter: Setting the height of the AppBar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089994/flutter-setting-the-height-of-the-appbar)