# How to prevent AppBar from clipping its children in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I want to display some content below an `AppBar` in a way that looks like it's part of the app bar itself. To achieve that I set the app bar's `elevation` to 0 and create a container below it with the content. This container then has a shadow to make it look like it's part of the app bar.

What I can't figure out is a way to make it so that the app bar doesn't clip the ink splash resulting from taps on buttons in the app bar, since it looks kinda off.

[Example of the behavior on DartPad](https://dartpad.dev/?id=f122d44e4e2c0486c44e29f42720d203&null_safety=true), and a screenshot below:

[image: Screenshot showing clipped ink splash]

**Code pasted from DartPad below:**

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
          elevation: 0,
          actions: [
            IconButton(
              icon: const Icon(Icons.settings_rounded, color: Colors.black),
              onPressed: () {},
            ),
          ],
        ),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 32,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[100]!,
                boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey[600]!, blurRadius: 3)],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: The problem is happening because instead of increasing the appbar you put a column to simulate a larger app bar. You can see this if you change the app bar color. Just increase the app bar. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089994/flutter-setting-the-height-of-the-appbar

Comment: @bruno have a look at this link https://dartpad.dev/?id=f122d44e4e2c0486c44e29f42720d203&null_safety=true

Comment: @JahidulIslam I can't see your changes, I think if you make changes to the DartPad I shared only you can see them

Comment: @ClaudioCastro I understand what's happening, I'm asking if there's a way to prevent the clipping, though. (I know I can work around it by making the AppBar larger, but that's not what I'm trying to solve here.)

Comment: To clarify, I know it's possible because I've seen it done in other apps. I just want to know if it's possible with the default AppBar or if they implemented a custom solution

Answer (score 1):

Lets try with `preferred size` and as well as you can try with `toolbarHeight: 25,`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: PreferredSize(
            preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(25.0), // here the desired height
            child: AppBar(
              backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
              elevation: 0,
              actions: [
                IconButton(
                  icon: const Icon(Icons.settings_rounded, color: Colors.black),
                  onPressed: () {},
                ),
              ],
            )),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
        body: Column(
          children: [
            Container(
              height: 32,
              margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3),
              decoration: BoxDecoration(
                color: Colors.grey[100]!,
                boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey[600]!, blurRadius: 3)],
              ),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Either you can use `PreferredSize` or just try `splashRadius` property of `IconButton`

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      debugShowCheckedModeBanner: false,
      home: Scaffold(
        appBar: FAppBar(),
        backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100]!,
        body: Column(
          children: [
//             Container(
//               height: 32,
//               margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 3),
//               decoration: BoxDecoration(
//                 color: Colors.grey[100]!,
//                 boxShadow: [BoxShadow(color: Colors.grey[600]!, blurRadius: 3)],
//               ),
//             ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}

class FAppBar extends StatelessWidget implements PreferredSizeWidget {

  @override
  Size get preferredSize => const Size.fromHeight(100);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Material(elevation: 4,color: Colors.grey[100]!,
      child: Column(
        children: [
          AppBar(actions: [
            IconButton(splashRadius: 25,
                    icon: const Icon(Icons.settings_rounded, color: Colors.black),
                    onPressed: () {},
                  )
          ],elevation: 0, backgroundColor: Colors.grey[100]!,),
          const FlutterLogo()
        ],
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can set preferred size for appbar. Instead of adding container attaching to it.

```
 appBar:PreferredSize(
      preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(50.0), //  desired height for appbar
      child:  AppBar(
                 ..........
              ),
      ),
```