# how to reduce appbar size in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

I have a form page. At the top of the page I write the name of the form. But the problem is that this name takes up a lot of space (height). Is it possible to reduce this height ??
My image:

[image]

My code

```html
class Form_ttn extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsScreenState createState() => _SettingsScreenState();
}

class _SettingsScreenState extends State<Form_ttn> {
  bool lockInBackground = true;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(title: Text('ТТН'), centerTitle: true,
        backgroundColor: Colors.blueGrey,),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
```

Comment: See this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51089994/flutter-setting-the-height-of-the-appbar

Answer (score 0):

You can make a custom appbar using PreferredSize widget.

```
return Scaffold(
      appBar: CustomAppBar(height: 50....

...

PreferredSize CustomAppBar({
  BoxDecoration decoration,
  EdgeInsets padding,
  Widget child,
  double height,
}) {
  return PreferredSize(
    preferredSize: Size.fromHeight(height),

    child: Container(
      padding: padding,
      decoration: decoration,
      child: child
      ),
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to use SafeArea widget ,refer below code hope its help to you. refer SafeArea [here](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/SafeArea-class.html)

```
 return SafeArea(
  child: Scaffold(
    appBar: AppBar(
      centerTitle: true,
      title: Text(
        'Search Here',
      ),
        ),
    body: SingleChildScrollView(),
  ),
);
```

Your result screen-> [image]

Answer (score 0):

Set height using toolbarHeight in AppBar

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).